# Проблема с aiogram и schedule

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, schedule

Всем здравствуйте, я пишу телеграм бота на языке python и библиотеке aiogram, у меня есть два файла
main.py - код бота, mailing.py - тут работает модуль schedule(что позволяет в определенное время запускать функции). Во втором файле мне нужно передать данные в функцию из первого, но проблема в том что aiogram - асинхронная библиотека(функции записываются с async и внутри await) а действия во втором файле происходят в обычной функции

Бот должен отсылать сообщение по telegram id

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot
import config

bot = Bot(config.bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def send_mails(id, number):
    print(id, number)
    await bot.send_message(id, number)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Которые берутся из вот этой функции во втором файле

```
import time
import main
import schedule

def check_users():
    id = 234567
    number = 6
    main.send_mail(id, number)
    
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(check_users)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

***Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы всё работало коректно***

Comment: вообще-то принято использовать aioschedule

Answer (score 0):

`Aiogram` не разрешает создание потоков, которые не зарегестрированы в `executor`-e. Pешил вашу проблему без использования библиотеки `schedule`.

```
import asyncio


async def check_users():
    while True:
        id = 234567
        number = 6
        await main.send_mail(id, number)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(check_users())
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Модуль `schedule` не может работать асинхронно. об етом написано в документации