# Параллельное выполнение программы

Tags: python, многопоточность

Написан бот на библиотеке aiogram.
Сервер запущен. Кроме беспрерывной работы бота, сервер также должен принимать GET-запросы и обрабатывать их (в этот момент бот должен оставаться в рабочем состоянии)

То есть в один момент времени мои программа должна уметь выполнять два дела:

- Обрабатывать GET запросы
- Обрабатывать сообщения, который приходят боту

Сейчас я использую **aiogram** для бота и **aiohttp** для сервера

**Вот как выглядит код**:

```
def bot():
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


def server():
    web.run_app(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = mongoengine.connect(host=constant.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION, tlsCAFile=constant.CA)
    th_1 = Thread(target=bot)
    th_2 = Thread(target=server)

    th_1.start()
    th_2.start()

    th_1.join()
    th_2.join()
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: В чем конкретно вопрос-то? На верхнем уровне могу посоветовать для этого не многопоточность, а асихронность использовать, так как тут операции ввода-вывода выглядят неблокирующими. Если блокирующими - да, используйте  многопоточность.

Comment: @Сергей Вопрос в том, что я не понимаю как в одной программе параллельно может работать сервер и бот. Не ясна реализация.

Comment: если есть возможность делайте асинхронку. "Обрабатывать GET запросы" через какую библиотеку?

Comment: @СергейШашко Не принципиально. Если посоветуете очень буду рад.

Comment: @СергейШашко Асинхронно я тоже рассматриваю, но реализация не выходит. Получается запустить либо только сервер, либо бота, всё что после запуска сервера/бота не выполняется до завершения программы.

Comment: Иван, вы что-то делали в асинхронном режиме и вам не ясно, как реализовать данную конкретную задачу (тогда в чем отличие от других таких задач?), или вы просто не работали с асинхронностью/мультипотоковостью? Если есть уже решение нерабочее, то имеет смысл код тут поместить.

Comment: асинхронная библиотека aiohttp аналог синхронной библиотеке requests.

Comment: я же спрашивал "через какую библиотеку?"

Comment: @Сергей Не работал с асинхронностью/мультипотоковостью

Comment: @СергейШашко Вообще да, именно aiohttp я и использовал.

Comment: 'Если есть уже решение нерабочее, то имеет смысл код тут поместить.'

Comment: @СергейШашко Добавил код.

Comment: под асинхронку думаю разберетесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376257/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-aiogram-%d0%b8-schedule

Comment: @СергейШашко таким образом не работает сервер. Ошибка: RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Comment: У вас вообще-то не асинхронный код, а мультипотоковый...

Comment: @Сергей зато библиотеки асинхронные

Comment: @СергейШашко, это я автору писал. Его библиотек я вообще не вижу. Вижу только Thread. Ваш-то код как раз асинхронный. Но понял теперь, что про нерабочий сервер  он писал не про свой код, а про ваш.

Comment: Простите, я не автор ни этого, и не того кода :)